# Nodejs mocha/should on silent mode

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I try to find an option on mocha to avoid having so huge error explanation when one of my should assertion fail.

```
  5 passing (561ms)
  1 failing

  1) Actors Actors list should get a list of well formed actors:
 Uncaught AssertionError: expected ... to have property properties
  at test/actors.js:70:47
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Test.<anonymous> (test/actors.js:65:35)
  at Test.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:117:20)
  at _stream_readable.js:943:16
```

I'd like to have just the passing and failing infos but not the rest. Any idea ?

Cheers,

Comment: I can suggest to try another reporter for mocha. That one i wrote for myself. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mocha-better-spec-reporter